# Summing absolute values of HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap

How do I convert the double values to a positive number before summing this map.  In other words, trying to get the sum of absolute values before obtaining total.

```
Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("CAT",-9.3);
map.put("BYTE", 15.6);
map.put("JOB", -11.66);
map.put("VIS", 8.0);


double TotalAbs = map.values().stream()
                         .mapToDouble(w -> w)
                         .sum();
```

Trying to sum the absolute value of the doubles ==>  The answer should be 44.56  and not 2.64.
[image: Please click here for IMAGE from Excel]
Please help out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can try `Math.abs`. It will convert the negative numbers to positive.

```java
double totalAbs = map.values().stream()
                             .mapToDouble(w -> Math.abs(w))
                             .sum();
```

Comment: note that you can use method references `mapToDouble(Math::abs)`

Answer (score 0):

loop

```java
double sum = 0;

for (Double val : map.values())
    sum += Math.abs(val);
```

stream

```java
double sum = map.values().stream().map(Math::abs).reduce(Double::sum).orElse(0.0);
```

result:

```java
System.out.println(sum); // 44.56
```